# Memory Allocation in Spark(df)

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, memory

I have defined a df in spark and have applied some transformations(filter) and have stored it in the same df what happens to the memory allocated to the df.

```scala
df=rdd.filter1
df=df.fitler2
df.filter3
df.fitler4
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to look at it-

- Dataframe is immutable, thus for every operation that you apply on it
  a new Dataframe is created(with fresh memory allocated). So, the 'df'
  will  ultimately point to the dataframe returned by the last 'filter'
  operation.  Since everytime a new dataframe object is created - your
  question about 'change in memory allocation' stands invalid.
- If you mean - multiple filter operation will reduce the data and the
  memory required. The answer is 'Yes'. Due to filter operations the 
  dataframe partitions will shrink and 'less' memory would be occupied.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, nothing until you invoke some action like collecting data to driver or writing DF to file. All transformations in Spark are *lazy*.